# Cannot parse function in QGIS

Tags: python, qgis

I'm a bit stuck here, so any help is appreciated.

I have a QGIS layer (csv) which has three columns (**X, Node, Tapping**) in it. x is a value, the others are strings.

I want to add/substract values from **X**, based on the string (value) in the two columns.
For this, I've created a function. This function has two dictionaries, which include the node/tapping strings with associated values.

I've run this in a Jupyter notebook (by parsing fixed variables for node and tapping) and it parses through the definition and returns the correct value, which I can then add to **X**.

I've tried the same in QGIS (function editor), but when I call the definition in the expression builder I get: **function is called with the wrong number of arguments. Expected 0 but got 2**, which seems odd to me since it was defined to parse two (in this case) strings.

**Function**

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def dbaddition(val1, val2):
    Node_settings = {"Node1: Amp2-A (11a02)":6,
                    "Node2: Amp1-B (21B01)":5,
                    "Node1: Amp1-B (11b01)":5,
                    "Node2: Amp2-A (21A02)":6,
                    "Node2: Amp3-B (21B03)":10,
                    "Node2: Indoor Loop 23B (21B02)":5,
                    "Node2: Amp3-A (21A03)":9.5,
                    "Node2: Amp1-A (21A01)":7,
                    "Node2: Indoor Loop 20B (21B02)":5,
                    "Node1: Amp1-A (11a01)":0,
                    "Node3: Amp2-B (31B02)":5,
                    "Node3: Amp4-B (31B04)":0,
                    "Node3: Amp1-B (31B01)":0,
                    "Node3: Amp4-A (31A04)":2,
                    "Node1: Amp2-B (11b02)":5,
                    "Node1: Amp3-A (11A03)":0}
    Tapping_settings = {"6W":7.8,
                    "3W":4.8,
                    "1.5W":1.8,
                    "1W":0,
                    "0.6W":-2.2,
                    "0.4W":-4}
    Node_dB = Node_settings.get(val1,0)
    Tap_dB = Tapping_settings.get(val2, 0)
    speaker_change = float(Node_dB) + float(Tap_dB)
    return speaker_change
```

**called by expression:**
dbaddition("Node", "Tapping")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to redefine the definition to:
def dbaddition(val1, val2, feature, parent):